# Just want to check if the way i have used the assignment expression in python 3.8 program is correct or not

Tags: python-3.8

According to Heron's formula for finding area of a triangle , if the sides of a triangle  are a, b & c is :

```
s = (a+b+c) / 2
area =sqrt( s * (s-a) * (s-b) * (s-c))   # sqrt means square root
```

so for finding the area of the triangle using Heron's formula in Python, if I write code like this, will it be a valid practise? I have used assignment expression while calculating the area.

```
a = int(input("Enter value of first side"))                # Assuming value is integer
b = int(input("Enter value of second side"))               # Assuming value is integer
c = int(input("Enter value of third side"))                # Assuming value is integer
area = ((s := (a+b+c) /2) *(s -a)*(s-b)*(s-c))**0.5    
print("Area of the triangle is", area)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, program counts correct. There is a one drawback in input: I recommend to add '\n' in input because it is uncomfortable to enter values without any space near text. In this code I fixed that. But you need to add checking if sides can make triangle.

```
a = int(input("Enter value of first side"))                // Assuming value is integer
b = int(input("Enter value of second side"))               // Assuming value is integer
c = int(input("Enter value of third side"))                // Assuming value is integer
area = ((s := (a+b+c) /2) *(s -a)*(s-b)*(s-c))**0.5    
print("Area of the triangle is", area)
```

Comment: Just need your suggestions on using assignment expression in calculating the area. if the use of assignment expression is a valid use case or not